# Grunt autorefresh from node

Tags: javascript, node.js, refresh, gruntjs

I used Grunt for three last days, I'm able to use this script from command line:

*web-server/Gruntfile.js*

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

    var concat = require('./config/grunt-concat.json');
    var uglify = require('./config/grunt-uglify.json');

    // Overload uglify, add target.
    uglify.my_target.files[concat.final.dest] = concat.final.src

    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
        concat: concat,
        uglify: uglify
    });
}
```

What I want to do is:

1. Config the target file in my config file (json) and not here. But I don't know how reference another config json file from a config json file. (I guess it's not possible from JSON, but it looks like Grunt could be able to do it, so I assume it's possible)
2. Don't use CLI but automatically run this script on server start. (On the app.js I guess)
3. Automatically reload the script when some JS files are changed (update/delete/create) to not have to stop and start the node server. (Only for files used in the browser, of course I'll still have to stop/run the server if I change the server files).

I don't know how reach these goals, I assume there are a lot of Grunt modules and some of them could help me but I don't know them. Thank you.

Comment: A solution could be to use my IDE to watch my files and recompile everything on each change. I use WebStorm 7.0.2 and I know it's possible, I'll try do to it like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found here:
[How run grunt when server start from node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20307913/how-run-grunt-when-server-start-from-node)

About the part to refresh it once file is changed I won't do like this, I'll use a supercontroller to see the http request and automatically rebuild the source when page is loaded in the browser, a simple refresh.

Or change my source code and don't use the generated files in development. Probably the better way.